# AngularJS module dependencies - how many times can I list them?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I scaffolded a simple Angular app using Yeoman, and I've been playing with it ever since.

Inside the file `app.js`, which is the first one listed as a `<script>` inside `index.html`, I define the main module as:

```
angular.module('myMod', [])
    .config(...)
```

Note the empty array of dependencies.

Now, when I want to, say, add a filter to this module, I create a `myFilter.js` file (which I load *after* `app.js` inside `index.html`); `myFilter.js` consists of:

```
angular.module('myMod').filter(...)
```

Note there's just one parameter to the `module()` function. If I pass the empty array of dependencies as a parameter to *this* `module()` function, really nothing appears on screen.

I've been playing with a bunch of other files which extended `myMod` with controllers, and passing `[]` as a parameter to the `angular.module()` function breaks my app every time.

It seems to me like I can only call `angular.module()` once using the second parameter, which may have some sense (how many times do I want to list my dependencies? What about consistency?). Is it that way?

If it is, is there some standard place where to list dependencies for a module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

angular.module("myModule",["dependencyA"]) will create a new module (this will crash if module allready exists.)
angular.module("myModule") uses an already known module.

This will also affect how you need to load the scripts in the index.html

Answer (score 2):

You should declare your dependencies only once. In addition, it's best practice to keep all of your filters as a separate module that your app depends on, for example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.directives', 'myApp.someOtherDependency']);
```

then, you would define your filters as a module that your app is dependant on:

```
angular.module('myApp.filters', []).filter(...)
```

Comment: Ok, got it. Is the dot notation (like in `myApp.filters`) just a convention?

Comment: Yes the dotnotation is just convention.